# Symbolic expression simplification in Julia Symbolics

Tags: julia, symbolic-math

I have a piece of code here in Julia:

```
   using Symbolics
  @variables x y z
3-element Vector{Num}:
 x
 y
 z

julia> q = [x y z]*[1 2 3;4 5 6;5 4 2]*[x y z]'
1×1 Matrix{Num}:
 x*(x + 4y + 5z) + y*(2x + 5y + 4z) + z*(3x + 6y + 2z)

simplify(q,expand=true)
```

`simplify(q,expand=true)` is not giving any better results.

How to expand the expression `q` correctly in julia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that `q` is a `1×1 Matrix{Num}`, and Symbolics doesn't like that. Select the first element from the matrix though, and it works fine:

```
simplify(q[1], expand = true) # x^2 + 5(y^2) + 2(z^2) + 6x*y + 8x*z + 10y*z
```

Comment: Maybe the three-argument method of `dot` results in a scalar in the first place.

Comment: @phipsgabler can you elaborate? I'm aware of linear algebra and dot products, but I wouldn't say it was my expertise

Comment: I was under the impression that it was using matrix multiplication, not dot products?

Comment: They are evaluating a quadratic form. `dot` has a [specific method](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.dot-Tuple{Any,%20Any,%20Any}) for that case. If we're lucky, Symbolics makes that result in a scalar (which it should be), I just can't test it right now.

Comment: oh right! Yep, I tried something similar before which didn't work, but this does: `simplify(dot([x y z],[1 2 3;4 5 6;5 4 2]*[x y z]'), expand=true)`

Comment: it's quite annoying that simplify doesn't show an error of some kind. Unless of course it can work in some intuitive way on matrices which means this error is unavoidable